# Google Analytics showing wrong page extensions

Tags: seo, google-analytics

We've recently re-designed our site and moved from a static site to a custom CMS, which instead of storing content of in the database stores the entire page and generates folders named after the page you create which holds an index.php file in it and I've done all the 301 redirects from our old .html pages to the new .php pages, however in google analytics Content -> Overview -> Site Content I see pages views for the homepage, but it reads /index.html which is the old index.html file that doesn't exist anymore, so when I try to open the page (via the  arrow icon next the page) i get a 404 error but it seems to be tracking it, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Even pages that I know are new are showing up as /services/index.html instead of /services/index.php

It's been two months since the re-design and re-launch, will this effect my seo and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have an SEO problem here. Log in to your Google Analytics account, drill down into your profile, then click "Admin" -> "Profile Settings".

On that screen, do you have `index.html` set as your default page? If so, you'll either want to remove that or change it to `index.php`. Google says it best:

> Even though www.example.com/ may be the same page as www.example.com/index.html, they show up as two separate entries in your reports. You can configure Google Analytics to treat them as the same page by defining the Default page for your profile

https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=1009675

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, It was set to index.html, yikes and I was getting a 404, but only because the default page was set to index.html instead of .php and I did not set a default for all pages to be .php in my htaccess file, probably should have done that instead.  I guess i'll wait for a few days till the new files extensions start to show up instead of .php.

Comment: Thanks for the help, changing the file extension was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 404 then your redirect is not working.
It may be that your 404 page handler also contains ga code and so you will see pages that 404 as page hits.